# Unknown WebMethod error while calling it from Jquery using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a web method that i am trying to call from jquery ajax but it is not getting invoked.
In firebug When i saw the response i get,

```
<title>Unknown web method MyMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName</title>
```

error.I am not able to get the reason why this error is coming when that method is available at the server  side..
Here is my client side code..

```
$("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var img = "image";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: img }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }).done(function (o) {
                console.log(["Response:", o]);
            });
        });
```

And here is my server side code..

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void MyMethod(string imageData)
{

    string fileNameWitPath = "D:/Kabir/custom_name.png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);//convert from base64
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue as i am completely struck into this.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Using this worked for me ***System.Web.Services.WebMethod***
*Try this*

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string imageData)
{
}
```

- **System.Web.Services.WebMethod()**
  Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute class
- **System.Web.Services.WebMethod**
  Adding this attribute to a method within an XML Web service created using ASP.NET makes the method callable from remote Web clients

#### If the above doesn't works, make sure that the `url` you are passing is correct. And still if it doesn't works [Check this out](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/571269/Unknownpluswebplusmethodplus-plusParameterplusname#answer1)

**This did worked on my system**
Default.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="excel">
    Here</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var img = "image";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
            data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: "Hello" }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).done(function (o) {
            console.log(["Response:", o]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string MyMethod(string imageData)
{
    return imageData;
}
```

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static void MyMethod(string imageData)
    {         but same error persisists

Comment: @Laxman check whether your `url` is correct.. If you are calling from the same page then it's ok... Or you may try using `~`..

Comment: Still error is same sir.Please sir check me at your side with the codes and help me as i am completely struck into the situation.

Comment: The webMethod is on the code behind file of the .aspx page i.e aspx.cs

Comment: Sir what is the starting tag of **</form>** ..Please post that also

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an answer about VB.net, you need to make your function `Public Shared`.  I just ran into this issue myself.